# hay alguna manera de obtener desde la API de blender la lista de modificadores que un objeto puede usar o aceptar

Tags: python, api, blender, scripting

ok, se que se puede obtener toda la lista de modificadores desde la API de blender pero me gustaría saber si se puede obtener una lista de modificadores que el objeto seleccionado puede usar o aceptar es decir si selecciono una curva ¿como puedo obtener la lista de modificadores que ese objeto puede usar o aceptar? lo mismo si selecciono una jaula(lattice) ¿como obtener la lista de modificadores que ese objeto puede aceptar o usar?